# Abbreviations add spaces when they shouldn't

Tags: abbreviations

I'm trying to create an abbreviations to insert a comment and to insert a `TODO` comment. I wrote them as following:

```
iab co /*__*/<Left><Left><Left>
```

This one produces the following (where it has three spaces)

```
/*__|_*/
```

And for the `TODO` comment, I wrote it like this:

```
iab td /*_TODO:_*/<Left><Left><Left>
```

This one produces

```
/* TODO:____|_*/
```

For some reason, vim adds extra spaces when interpreting the abbreviations. Could someone tell me why does it do this and how can I solve it?

Note: I replaced spaces with underscores for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens usually, because the abbreviation is triggered once you type a final space after the characters that trigger the abbreviation, e.g. after <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, so that the final space gets added at the cursor position after your expanded abbreviation.

One way around it is to make use of the `Eatchar` function mentioned at the [help](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/eda9e9c2fe4577ad451418253b990a3f60b70444/runtime/doc/map.txt#L960-L966) (there is no actual helptag for it, you can do `:helpgrep Eatchar` to find it).

Here is the definition from the help together with your TODO abbreviation.

```
func Eatchar(pat)
   let c = nr2char(getchar(0))
   return (c =~ a:pat) ? '' : c
endfunc
iab td /* TODO: */<Left><Left><Left><c-r>=Eatchar('\s')<cr>
```

Comment: Super. You clarified it very well. For me it added more spaces because I was hitting tab after the trigger and not space. Now I modified the abbreviation so that the added space is considered in the abbreviation. Thank you